# In ffmpeg , How to add a delay of 5 seconds to the audio and 2 seconds to the video

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg library to merge a video with an audio and it does work fine , basically now i want to give a delay of 5 seconds to the audio and 2 seconds to the video , can you please help with the command that does that . Thank you in advance

- Code to check

```
 public void Merge() {

      
        String videoId  = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        String videoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/silent_video.mp4"; // change video name
        String audioPath  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/wa_audio.wav"; // change audio name
        String videoOutPut  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/" + "Merged Video " + videoId + ".mp4"; // output path
        String[] c = {
                "-i",
                videoPath,
                "-i",
                audioPath,
                "-c:v", "copy" , "-c:a", "aac", "-map", "0:v:0", "-map", "1:a:0", "-shortest",
                videoOutPut
             };

        MergeVideo(c);
    }


private void MergeVideo(String[] co){
        // callback result after merging video and audio

        FFmpeg.executeAsync(co, new ExecuteCallback() {
            @Override
            public void apply( long executionId, int returnCode ) {
                // callback
                Log.d("File Tag" , "return  " + returnCode);
                Log.d("File Tag" , "executionID  " + executionId);
                Log.d("File Tag" , "FFMPEG  " +  new 
                FFmpegExecution(executionId,co));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding the argument `-itoffset` folled by the value in seconds.

```
String[] arguments = new String[]{
        "-itsoffset", "5", "-i", audiopath, "-i", videoPath", "-map", "0:v", "-map", "1:a", "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "copy", "-shortest", "videoOutPath"
};
```

Explanation

`-itsoffset 5 -i audiopath` offsets timestamps of streams by 5 seconds in the input file that follows the option. Read more about itsoffset [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)